# control statement throwing arithmetic exception

Tags: java, loops

this was supposed to be fairly simple, but apparently somethings wrong with my control boolean, when I input a negative number instead of ending the loop it throws an exception, any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class AverageMinMax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double average;
        int count = 0, sum = 0, next;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        boolean areMore = true;
        System.out.println("Please enter the  numbers you wish to evaluate:");
        System.out.println("Followed by a negative number");
        // not sure why i used a do while loop but it works i guess
        do {
            next = keyboard.nextInt();
            sum = sum + next;
            next++;
            if (next < 0)
                areMore = false;
        } while (areMore == true);
        
        {

            sum = sum + next;
            average = sum / count;

            {// the minmum and max values
                if (next > max)
                    max = next;
                if (next < min)
                    min = next;
            }
            System.out.println("Your average is: " + average);
            System.out.println("Your maximum number is: " + max);
            System.out.println("Your minimum number is: " + min);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.test.task.AverageMinMax.main(AverageMinMax.java:29)
```

Comment: `count` is always `0` when calculating `average`. It results in `ArithmeticException`. The reason is you *cannot divide by zero*.

Comment: how would you fix this?

Comment: `next++;` doesn't make any sense. Why would you increment the value entered by the user? Perhaps you meant that to be `count++;`, which would also fix your problem? --- *Side note:* Why would you sum and count the negative value entered by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues:

- You increase `next` instead of count.
- Outsider (`sum = sum + next`) is also wrong. You should not add next after loop breaks.
- Min-max should be calculated inside the loop.

Some improvement suggestions:

1. Use while it is cleaner than do-while.
2. Use `hasNextInt` to check if it is a number or not.
3. If your input is a `char` or `any special character` while loop breaks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class AverageMinMax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sum = 0, average =0;
        int count = 0, next = 0;
        
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.println("Please enter the  numbers you wish to evaluate:");
        System.out.println("Followed by a char or any special character to calculate and exit");
        // use while it is more cleaner.
        // use hasNextInt to check if it is number or not
        // if your input is a char or any special character while loop breaks
        while (keyboard.hasNextInt()) {

            next = keyboard.nextInt();
            sum = sum + next;
            
            // the minmum and max values
            if (next > max)
                max = next;
            if (next < min)
                min = next;
            
            count++;
        }

        average = sum / count;

        System.out.println("Your average is: " + average);
        System.out.println("Your maximum number is: " + max);
        System.out.println("Your minimum number is: " + min);

    }
}
```

Comment: True, using while is better +1.

Answer (score 1):

### Issues

1. count is not incremented and its causes divide by `0` error
2. computation of max, min, sum, average seems incorrect

### solution

1. Repeated read input(integer) from user
2. if the input is positive, add to sum, update min, update max and update count
3. if its negative, break the input loop
4. if any input is passed, then compute average
5. if no input is passed, then do not compute average

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class AverageMinMax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0, sum = 0, min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        System.out.println("Please enter the  numbers you wish to evaluate.");
        System.out.println("Followed by a negative number to stop input");

        do {
            final int next = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (next < 0) {
                break;
            }
            sum = sum + next;
            max = Math.max(max, next);
            min = Math.min(min, next);
            count++;
        } while (true);

        if (count > 0) {
            double average = (sum * 1.0) / count; // need to multiply by 1.0 to have fraction
            System.out.println("Your average is: " + average);
            System.out.println("Your maximum number is: " + max);
            System.out.println("Your minimum number is: " + min);
        } else {
            System.out.print("No input to process");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting ArithmeticException because you initialize count to 0. But after that when you are getting input from console. instead of increasing the count and doing count++. You are doing next++ in the loop.

And also getting the min max should also needs to be done in loop currently they are just in block. Although they are not responsible for your error of divide by zero.

this line is

```
average = sum / count;
```